# Cropping an image using JS plugin | PhoneGap| iOS

Tags: ios, image, cordova, crop, cordova-3

I am new to using PhoneGap on iOS and was stuck at cropping an image using imgAreaSelect JS plugin. The code works well in the web browsers while doesn't show any change in the iOS simulator. The image is being imported from a local folder.The code used is as below:

```
$('#testimg').imgAreaSelect({
handles: true,
aspectRatio: '16:9'
});
```

Please let me know if there any other way to crop an image using PhoneGap?  This is how it looks in the web browser and the same does not happen in the iOS simulator.[image]

Answer (score 3):

The plugin imgAreaSelect probably wouldn't work. I have tried JCrop-http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html and it works perfectly fine. They explicitly mention that they have Touch support for iOS, Android, etc. Just follow the demo on the link.

Answer (score 1):

```
Jcrop Does'nt support touch event in phone gap so there is no need to use I have spend 3 hour on it. I just want to crop after upload image from camera or salary in phonegap. I use following  it is working fine.
```

https://github.com/acornejo/jquery-cropbox

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $targ_w = 640;
    $targ_h=280;
    $jpeg_quality = 90;

    $save=dirname(__FILE__).'/files/abcd.jpg';
    $src = dirname(__FILE__).'/img/img.jpg';
    $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    $dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );
   imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],$targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($dst_r,null ,$jpeg_quality);

    exit;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0041)http://acornejo.github.io/jquery-cropbox/ -->
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>jQuery-cropbox</title>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <link type="text/css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery.cropbox.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/hammer.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cropbox.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" defer="">
    $( function () {
     $(function () {
    var r = $('#results'),
        x = $('.cropX', r),
        y = $('.cropY', r),
        w = $('.cropW', r),
        h = $('.cropH', r);

    $('#cropimage').cropbox({
        width: 500,
        height: 240
    }).on('cropbox', function (event, results, img) { console.log("on crop");
        x.text(results.cropX);
        y.text(results.cropY);
        w.text(results.cropW);
        h.text(results.cropH);
        $("#x").val(results.cropX);
        $("#y").val(results.cropY);
        $("#w").val(results.cropW);
        $("#h").val(results.cropH);

    });
});
});
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="index.php" method="post" onsubmit="return checkCoords();">
          <div style="width:100%;">
          <img id="cropimage" alt="" src="img/img.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div id="results"> <b>X</b>: 
        <span class="cropX"></span>
         <b>Y</b>: <span class="cropY"></span>
         <b>W</b>: <span class="cropW"></span>
         <b>H</b>: <span class="cropH"></span>


                    <input type="text" name="x" id="x" size="4" />
                    <input type="text" name="y" id="y" size="4" />
                    <input type="text" name="w" id="w" size="4" />
                    <input type="text" name="h" id="h" size="4" />

        </div>
        <input type="submit"  />
</form>

</body></html>
```